# Media screen for mobile devices not working correctly

Tags: css

I have the following media screen resolutions.

```
  /*IPHONE 5 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :
568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.box h1 {
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
}
/*IPHONE 5 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :
568px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.box h1 {
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
}
 /*IPHONE 7 */
 @media screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width :
 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {
 .box h1 {
    font-size: 2em !important;
 }
}
/*IPHONE 7 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width :
667px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.box h1 {
    padding: 55px;
    font-size: 2.1em !important;
}
}
```

The Problem is now, that if i change something inside the IPHONE 5 landscape , it dosen't do anything. But if i change something inside the IPHONE 7 resolution landscape it takes effect for the IPHONE 5 and IPHONE 7.
So what is wrong ?

**EDIT**

My HTML:

```
<div class="box">

    <h1 id="suchen"><span>Suchen</span></h1>

    <h1><span>Favoriten</span></h1>

    <h1><span>Neu</span></h1>

</div>
```

Comment: add your html code

Comment: Have edit my post

Comment: add your iphone 5 css below the iphone 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 /*IPHONE 7 */
 @media screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width :
 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {
 .box h1 {
    font-size: 2em !important;
 }
}
/*IPHONE 7 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width :
667px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.box h1 {
    padding: 55px;
    font-size: 2.1em !important;
}
}
 /*IPHONE 5 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :
568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.box h1 {
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
}
/*IPHONE 5 */
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :
568px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.box h1 {
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thx but now the IPHONE 7 takes effect of the IPHONE 5 style so it's completly inverse